# How to implement the two categories of the same content type to automatically generate a new aggregation page?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

example: there are two taxonomy fields of each article, a taxonomy is regional, another is the attribute，I want to achieve the "regional + attribute = regional attribute" automatically generated such a new aggregation page.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new view, go to `admin/structure/views/add`

**Show:** Content **of type:** All

✅ Create a page

**Display Format:** Unformatted List **of:** Fields

<kbd>Save and Edit</kbd>

Now in your view, Click on Advanced (located in the right side).

**RELATIONSHIPS** click <kbd>add</kbd>

Select ✅ Taxonomy terms on node

For **Vocabularies** checkmark your vocabs and then checkmark ✅ require relationship.

Then in **FILTER CRITERIA** <kbd>add</kbd> Has taxonomy term

✅ Autocomplete, then type `regional, attribute`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but did not realize, this is to show the current classification of all the articles below, did not realize the automatic filtering of the two conditions.